# Query to increment column not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

I'm trying to update a column `count` using this code:

```
UPDATE Tabelltest
SET COUNT = COUNT + 1
WHERE name = 'bla'
```

However, my count variable is still has the value `0`.

When I do `count = 2`, it will be successfully updated but I want it to increment by one instead.

Comment: What is your column type set to? Plus try `count +1`

Comment: Also, what's the initial value? If it's `null`, as opposed to `0`, I'm not sure you can increment it.

Comment: I was thinking of that too before writing my initial comment, but said to myself "Nah, couldn't be". @andrewsi +1

Comment: ARe you running this in php?show the code.

Comment: As Andrew already stated, plus make sure there is already a value of `1` in your column, otherwise it won't work.

Comment: Is the value `0` or `NULL`?  The behavior suggests that it is really `NULL`.

Comment: column type is INT , its 0

Comment: if my Column value is 1 and i do it with COLUMN = COLUMN +1 it dindt work either

Comment: Then show us your full PHP/SQL code. @user3369579 or I will vote to close

Comment: mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE Tabelltest SET numbcount = numbcount +1  WHERE name = 'bla')); ------ i think is a problem in MYSQLI cause if i copy the code into PHPMYADMIN and  query it workes fine

Comment: eh cant use this cause i want that my Column numbcount is always incresed by 1...

Comment: Ok, you have and if it's your actual code `mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE Tabelltest SET numbcount = numbcount +1 WHERE name = 'bla'));` you forgot a closing `"` so do `mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE Tabelltest SET numbcount = numbcount +1 WHERE name = 'bla'"));` @user3369579

Comment: im sorry forgott the ' " ' only here

Comment: again  if i do numbcount = 2 it works perfectly

Comment: Ok, well it seems obvious then that you either don't have a column called `name` and/or there is no value in that column with the word `bla` in it. @user3369579 I have a similar piece of code as yours and it works perfectly well. If one of those conditions isn't met, your query fails.

Comment: Plus, make sure your table is called `Tabelltest` and not `Tableltest`

Comment: cant upvote u but u got it right thx

Comment: You're welcome. About which comment was that? (I addressed two possible factors) Let me know so I can make it an answer to close the question. @user3369579

Comment: I used my comments and placed them in my answer below. Tick the white checkmark till it turns Green (next to my answer) to accept as the solution in order to close the question, since a solution has been found. @user3369579

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following has been made as an answer, where the OP states *"cant upvote u but u got it right thx "*

It seems obvious then, that you either don't have a column called `name` and/or there is no value in that column with the word `bla` in it.

<strike>I have a similar piece of code as yours and it works perfectly well.</strike>

If one of those conditions isn't met, your query fails.

Plus, make sure your table is called `Tabelltest` and not `Tableltest` or  `Tabletest`

That could be a typo which will make all the difference.

Add error reporting to the top of your file(s)

-mysqli-

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
```

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

PDO

- http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php
- http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php

MySQL (error reporting links)

- http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php
- http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php
- http://www.php.net/mysqli_error